# Remove tab from tabstrip in userform - vba excel

Tags: forms, vba, excel, tabs

I have a form with several controls. It includes a tabstrip with one tab. I allow users to add tabs, by clicking commandbutton1. So far so well.

Now I also want users to be able to remove the last tab (except for the first one) by clicking commandbutton2. The problem is that, despite the fact that I've been searching for about two hours, I cannot find the right syntax for method "remove" when it comes to tabs. Any help appresiated.

**edited:**

Making the above question more specific: What's the right syntax for "remove" method when it's parameter is a string-variable and not a specific tab name. (for example removing the current tab)

e.g.
It would be great if one of the following would work:

```
Sub test
    Dim nm As String

    With TabStrip1
        nm = .SelectedItem.Name
        .Tabs.Remove (nm)
    End With
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test
    With TabStrip1
        .Tabs.Remove (.SelectedItem.Name)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can Remove a Tab by the `TabStrip1.Tabs.Remove` Line.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Insert the Tap Test
       TabStrip1.Tabs.Add ("Test")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()'Removes the Tap Test
       TabStrip1.Tabs.Remove ("Test")
    End Sub
```

The Rest you can Handle with a something Like this:

```
If TabStrip1.Tabs.Count >= 2 Then
    TabStrip1.Tabs.Remove (TabStrip1.Tabs.Count - 1)
End If
```

You have to check fist if there are more then two Taps. If yes delete the last Tap.
The Hint her is, that the Index starts with the Second Tap!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Your answer worked perfect, but I did not state clearly exhactly what I wanted. I have edited my question. If you could give it a try, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the way.
`remove` method accepts a tab's `caption` as an argument and not its `name`.

In this case the following worked great:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim nm As String

    With TabStrip1
        nm = .SelectedItem.Caption
        .Tabs.Remove (nm)
    End With
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    With TabStrip1
        .Tabs.Remove (.SelectedItem.Caption)
    End With
End Sub
```